# Custom Login Instagram API iOS

Tags: ios, api, authentication, instagram

I'm developing an application for iOS with the authentication, using Instagram API.

My code for authentication works good:

```
NSString *fullURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://instagram.com/oauth/authorize/?client_id=%@&redirect_uri=%@&response_type=code",KCLIENTID,kREDIRECTURI];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:fullURL];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

instagramConnectWebView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds]; 
instagramConnectWebView.delegate = self;
[instagramConnectWebView loadRequest:request];
```

When the request is sent, my webView shows the standard Instagram login interface, where user has to insert username and password to login. If login succeed, app is redirected to my redirection-url, where i get the code and the token of this user.

My question is really simple, is there a way to customize standard interface of Instagram login? I'd like to insert in my app two simple UITextField (One for username and one for the password) and when user clicks on my UIButton login, application should send (POST or GET?) username and password to Instagram, and return response (Login success or not).

I hope i explained myself.

Thanks.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution? I am also trying to figure this out.

Comment: I didn't, i don't know if it's possible and i'm still using the standard Instagram api's interface :(

Comment: As a user I would not trust an app that creates its own login screen for a service. I think even though the Instagram oauth login screen is ugly, I think it is better to keep it, since the users find it more safe to hand their credentials directly to Instagram.

Answer (score 6):

You can make this by using javascript. by loading a web view in background :

You need to access the text field of that web view and pass value of your custom UItextfields and after that you can call webView's  "Submit" button's Onclick event.

```
NSString *javaScript = @"document.getElementById('id_username').value = 'tfusername'";
NSString *javaScript2 = @"document.getElementById('id_password').value = 'tfpassword'";
```

to evaluate each script you can call: `[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:javaScript];`

You can also call script to press login button. This same thing work for me. May be this will help you.

Comment: Update: Instagram just changed their login page and this no longer works.

Comment: @abhineet can i login with my own textfield of username, password and UIButton in Instagram..? please help me. Thanks.

Comment: @Esha can you please help me to making demo for custom login of Instagram ? Please .

Comment: Although it might work for some user it is not a reliable solution. Instagram can change its login page anytime and your will be broken.

Answer (score 0):

I have created a wrapper for Instagram API for iOS. Take a look at this [link](https://github.com/kkocabiyik/KIngstagram) . This will also give an idea of what you need to do.

Comment: hi @kkocabiyik can i login with my own `textfield` of username, password and `UIButton` in Instagram..? please help me.